# Построение дерева Хаффмана

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Мне нужно построить дерево Хаффмана. Программу я пишу на C# и для представления дерева я выбрал встроенную структуру SortedList. У меня возникло два вопроса по построению дерева Хаффмана.

1. Построение дерева не удастся выполнить в один цикл?
2. При построение дерева Хаффмана мне нужно выбирать узлы с наименьшими весами не имеющих родителей. В итоге выйдет родительский узел, вес которого равен сумме весов его двух потомков. Для того чтобы программа не трогала те узлы, которые уже имеют родителей, мне нужно завести список свободных узлов, куда также будут добавляться созданные родительские узлы и удаляться узлы потомки из которых создан данный родительский узел. Вопрос, в виде чего в программе можно представить список свободных узлов?

Answer (score 2):

1. В классическом алгоритме кодирование происходит в два прохода. Существует [адаптивный вариант](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.90.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BF.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B6.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B5), в котором сжатие делается за один проход.
2. Я бы использовал SortedSet, где узлы отсортированы по весу. Тогда алгоритм будет очень простым (псевдокод, так как не знаю C#):

   ```
   S <- SortedSet of leaf nodes
   While size(S) != 1:
       Node1 = S.Min
       S.remove(Node1)
       Node2 = S.Min
       S.remove(Node2)
       Parent = createParent(Node1, Node2)
       S.add(Parent)

   Root = S.Min
   ```